# .htaccess ошибка при редиректе на https

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Перепробывал уже все конфиги с https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/kak-dobavit-redirekt/redirekt-cherez-htaccess

Либо браузер выдает ошибку о цикле либо  при такой конфигурации:
https://prnt.sc/recc6g

Отправляет: 
https://prnt.sc/recddc

Подскажите пожалуйста, ошибка на моей стороне? Если да - то в чем?